# Having jframe troubles, dont want to use, will this work

Tags: java, button, graphics, jframe, jbutton

Why wil this not run. 
Jframe isnt an option what can i use, and how come i have to have 
graphics g as a component? as well as how is Graphics g set up as a parameter ?

class Tables{

public staic void main (String [] args){

```
Button mainscreen = new Button(Graphics g);

g.drawRect(10, 10, 50, 50);
```

}
}

Comment: No. That will not work (`Graphics` is, fundamentally, a context from the operating system). Why can't you use `JFrame`?

Comment: Just what are you actually trying to do?

Comment: A button isn't a window

Comment: make a gui, but why are constructors called graphics g objects without a separating comma inside the constructer as: (Graphics g).

Comment: Thanks Elliot i understand !

Answer (score 1):

> will this work

No.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/step3.html) for working examples of how to do painting.

And yes you need a window of some kind (JFrame or JDialog) to display the panel.

If you don't want the borders then you can use an `undecorated` frame.

```
JFrame frame = new JFrame();
frame.setUndecorated(true);
```

Comment: And [How to Create Translucent and Shaped Windows](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/trans_shaped_windows.html) will basically "hide" the window